# how to make the live chart image to the right?

Tags: javascript

```
http://phplist.xxmn.com/test.html
```

how to make the live chart image to the right?

`<script src="http://chatserver.comm100.com/js/LiveChat.js?siteId=117659&amp;planId=646&amp;partnerId=-1" type="text/javascript"></script>` i downloaded the `js` file(`http://chatserver.comm100.com/js/LiveChat.js`) and uploaded it to my site's directory. and declared those variables in the front of the code.

```
(
var siteId=117659;
var planId=646;
var partnerId=-1
)
```

but it can't work, why? how to correct it.

Comment: How about inserting the code inside of a float:right; div container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've got not control over the script which frequently shifts the element to the left, add an own stylesheet, using `!important`.

```
<style>
#comm100_FloatImageButton {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: auto !important; /* This style will not be overridden by the script */
    right: 0 !important; /* This property will neither be overridden*/
}
</style>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PzRmk/**

Comment: many thanks. but i don't know why the !important can work. when i delete the !important, the style can't effect.

Comment: The `!important` flag increases the weight of the rule, causing later definitions to be overruled.